# Angular 8: value used in comonent.html is not the value in the component.ts (azure app service)

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, azure-devops

I got a really strange behavior in one of my angular app.
In a component.html, I want to display "UAT" and color the angular mat markups with a bright orange when in UAT, otherwise it should be blue and no mention of of UAT anywhere (aka PROD).

In local, no problem. when I deploy to azure nothing makes sense. So here is a bit of my code.

In my angular solution I got this env.json file that looks like this

```
{
"production": false,
"isTestEnvironment": false,
}
```

In VSTS, I build the app once, and use it for all deployements. So in the UAT deployement, I replace the iSTestingEnvironment with "true", and ship it to azure.
for production deployement, I replace production with "true", isTestingEnvironment by "false", and ship it.

This env.json is extracted using something like this in the app.module.ts

```
const appInitializer = {
 provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
 useFactory: configFactory,
 deps: [AppConfig],
 multi: true
};
```

and appInitializer is registered in the providers section.
And the AppConfig injectable is:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
```

import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

```
@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {
 public config: any;

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 public load() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   this.http.get('env.json').subscribe((p: string) => {
    this.config = p;
    resolve(true);
   });
  });
 }
}
```

In my component's contructor, I start by getting the isTestingEnvironment:

```
this.isTestEnvironment = appConfig.config.isTestEnvironment;
```

At this very moment, when I console.log the values, it is always correct:
In UAT, it's true.
In PROD, it's false.
And in local, it's watchever i put in the env.json, even when I hot change the value while ng serve is running.

When I look at the env.json that is deployed (using kudu/powershell), the  file is well formed with the right values across all environments.

So far so good. 
But this code then breaks everything in the component.html:

```
    <h5 style="margin: auto;" *ngIf="isTestEnvironment">UAT</h5>
```

In UAT and PROD, it always show up. regardless of the isTestingEnvrionment being true or false just instants before in the console log.
However it works ust fine in local debug using VSC (1.42.1) and node (v10.18.1).

At this point, Angular is telling true == false, so I'm at a complete loss.

I triple checked, at no point in the angular solution is the variable isTestingEnvironment set to a value anywhere else than in the env.json. So yeah, I'm either completely missing something obvious or something is really wrong in my code.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using the default isDevMode() function from @angular/core ?

Comment: "In VSTS, I build the app once, and use it for all deployements." This seems to be your problem. `environment.ts` is used during build time. Chaging its values after a build has no impact. `environment.ts` is probably not the right place to put this configuration in.

Comment: Hello, @Fmerco I did not know that but as @ tom-van-green said, it relies on environment.ts which is "compiled" and modying it after build is useless.
@ tomvangreen I'm not using environment.ts in my current build. I'm using a custom, standalone, file named env.json which is deployed alongside the main-xxxx.ts on the azure server. I'm now trying to figure out a way to read env.json before boostrap.

I realy don't want to build for each environment, it's a pipeline design flaw in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out.

TLDR : It was caused by VSTS release task called "Azure App Service Deploy" that change the variables to string in the "File Transform & Variable Substitution Option" section.

After looking again at the deployed file I finaly saw that the file that is :

```
{
"isTestEnvironment": true,
}
```

in my sources had became :

```
{
"isTestEnvironment": "true",
}
```

on the azure server.
This caused every check we made against this supposedly boolean variable bogus, since a non-empty string is equivalent to true in js.

So I'm now using JSON.parse(myVariable) when I extract it from the env.json file.
I could reproduce it in local and tested it. It works.

To anyone using the same releas etask as we do, be careful that boolean will be changed into string. I checked our release pipeline variable and they are NOT declared with quotes around them; plain simple true/false values.

In any case, thank you guys for giving potential workarounds.